# Is there a module for a DS28CM00 serial chip?

Tags: drivers, kernel-modules

A google search reveals a patch for this Maxim/Dallas chip was added in 2008, but I can't track it down in Linux 4.1.

Does this module still exist in the 4.1 version of the kernel?

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not exist in Linux kernel 4.1.  It seems that [the patch in question](https://lkml.org/lkml/2008/10/7/160) had a v2 proposed, which was then [abandoned](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0810.2/2327.html).  The patch author seems to have opted to use the "at24" driver instead.